# How to reduce the screen resolution or the screen to 75% in the browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am developing one page layout but when I test the screen in normal size laptops in the browser it scrolls and when i reduce the zoom to 75% in the browser it fits the complete one screen layout. I want to know is there any way to fix it?
Html Code:

```
<div id="date-slider" class="dragdealer">
     <ul class="list_date" id="date"> 
         <li id="date1">
         </li>
         <li id="date2">
         </li>
         <li id="date3">
         </li>
         <li id="date4">
         </li>
         <li id="date5">
         </li>
         <li id="date6">
         </li>
         <li id="date7">
         </li>
     </ul>
  <div class="handle red-bar">
<span class="value"></span>
```

CSS:

```
.date_slide {
 height: 6.5em;
 background: #f2f2f2;
 margin-bottom: 6%;
 position: relative;
}

ul.list_date {
 list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 width: 100%;
}

ul.list_date li {
  width: 14.28%;
  float: left;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
 }

#date-slider .handle {
  height: 7.5em;
  line-height: 1em;
  border-radius: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: -6%;
}

 .dragslider {
   text-align: center;
   width: 450px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   display: block;
   position: relative;
   margin-bottom: 6%;
 }

 .dragdealer {
   position: relative;
   height: 30px;
   background: #EEE;
  }

  div#date-slider {
   width: 100%;
   height: 4.5em;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #f2f2f2;
   }

  .date_slide .dragdealer .red-bar {
     width: 70px;
     height: 92px;
     background: #ffdc0e;
     color: #000;
     font-size: 14px;
      line-height: 30px;
     text-align: center;
   }

   #date-slider span.value {
     font-size: 22px;
     white-space: pre-wrap;
     line-height: 1.4em;
     display: block;
     margin: 6px 0px;
   }
```

I have to fix this as the screen size reduces should fit the screen size

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking.. What do you have, and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: :D lol zooming out to fit the screen, you can never get it right for all resolutions you know there are many different screen sizes and ratios. Look around for `responsive design` and make it so it fits everything. Look into `media queries` and different measurement units like `em` and `%`

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky yeah I know that.. I am using em and % bothe where ever required but it still scrolls.

Comment: scolls horizontally or vertically, can you provide some sample

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky sample like cant provide the whole code.. wait i will update the code just tell me if you help me fix that...

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky hi I have updated the code can you see.

Comment: @Gavin Thomas I am trying to develope a page with one screen layout. It is showing proper layout in large screen but when i see in macbook pro or other dell normal size screen the one page layout scrolls and when I zoom out to 75% in the chrome browser it fits one page layout with proper design whatever I have develope. So i wanted to know is there any way fix it.

Comment: Read up on Responsive Design, Viewport sizes and Breakpoints.

Comment: check your css for `div#date-slider` I don't see why you need to translate to `-50%, -50%` and then give it `left` and `right` `50%` that seems to cancel out, but trying it out it creates a vertical scroll for some reason - not sure that is the actual problem, but its worth trying it out